# React Component Meant as Footer is Covering Cotent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TypeScript React component is meant to stay at the bottom of the page. I have position as fixed so it doesn't move with scrolling. The problem, however, is that it covers another component that is at the body of the page.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. You didn't really supply any information about your problem. Try sharing your code and the problem that you are experiencing so that we can help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please add code samples. There might be several reasons for this issue:

1. Did you give a valid top/bottom/left/right value in CSS? As you want to create a footer, it might be `bottom: 0; left: 0;`.
2. Do you know that elements with position fixed come out of the flow of your website? Any component on your website can go under/over the fixed element. In this case, your body is going under the fixed footer component. To solve this issue you can add a margin-bottom on the body equal to the height of your component.